# Apache not serving Static Files + Ubuntu

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, mod-jk

When I have enable mod_jk in Apache with Tomcat for web application.

After then Apache will not be able to serve static files from Apache directories.

Any Idea what is wrong in configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set below exception in jk.conf file

SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI ".(htm|html)$" no-jk

and also make below changes in 000-default.conf file

DocumentRoot /var/www
   
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all

JkMount /* ajp13